# Checkbox, when checked dissapears after refresh and never saved to the DB

Tags: mysql, reactjs

My checkbox is marking a noteid but whenever page is refreshed the checkbox vanishes. Also it's never saved to the database for some reason. Any ideas?

Part of the relevant code. ( full code in comments)

```
<div className="Data-flex" key={data.noteId}> <div className="NoteID" style={{ flex: 1 }}> {data.noteId} </div> <Checkbox style={{ flex: 1 }} onChange={handleStatus}
```

Function Below!

```
const [Status2, setStatus2] = useState(false);
const handleStatus = (event, data) => {
console.log("Marking todo ... Data : ", data);
setStatus2(true);
  };
```

Comment: On normal HTML at least, when a page is loaded, it loads the default value.  Are you SURE its not updating the db and just not display the correct results on the screen?  Because it might be changing but just your form isn't showing the change, but if it is NOT changing in the db, then that is your issue, its not passing it on the update/insert.
EDIT - the form would need some if/then logic to compare the default value to the db value, and if it matches you could add "checked" to the html to indicate when they match that one should be checked on page load.

Comment: Yea Ive checked the db and its not updating the values...

Comment: Okay, then do a manual check to display the results of the checkbox checking and make sure its passing that parameter, then if you find it is, make sure its the right data type, such as, if the checkbox = 1 vs if checkbox is = "1" ... make sure if its suppose to be an Integer you didn't leave it as a string, so it fails on the inserts.  Then if thats not it, post what you are using to do the insert and we can take a look at it.